# Having Problems In Nuke importing the pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pyside2, nuke

Within the VFX Software "Nuke" I can't seem to import the pandas module because it fails to find "numby"

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling pandas/nimby 2ce just to make sure nothing fishy is going on there.  I've also looked in the directory:

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

and sure enough numby is there.

I have been able to use pandas from within pycharm and from with maya with no issues, but for some reason it is causing problems in Nuke

```py
import pandas
```

The pandas module works from command line, PyCharm, and Maya, can't understand why I get this error:

```
# Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))

ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: numby is different to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this and was able to reproduce the error. It looks like it's possible there's a conflict with nuke's custom environment variables and paths.

If you add a "print(e)" on line#15 in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py" like this:

```
for dependency in hard_dependencies:
try:
    __import__(dependency)
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    missing_dependencies.append(dependency)
```

You'll get the following message in the console upon importing pandas:

> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely
>   you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. Here is how to
>   proceed:
>
> > - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`   (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
> > - If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:   your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
> > - If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
> >
> >   1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using C:\apps\Foundry\nuke\11-3v4\Nuke11.3.exe),
> >          and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
> >          interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
> >   2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
> >          https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
> >
> >      - how you installed Python
> >      - how you installed numpy
> >      - your operating system
> >      - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
> >      - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
> >
> >      Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
> >          an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

I stopped there, but is it possible perhaps to use subprocess for your purposes?